# Magento Virtual Host

Tags: php, apache, magento

I am trying to setup virtual host for `Magento`, but its not working, I created `magento.localhost.com.conf` in the `Apache2/sites-avaliable` directory, this is my file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin magento@localhost.com
    ServerName magento.localhost.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/magento_dev/public_html

    <Directory /srv/www/magento_dev/public_html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /srv/www/magento_dev/logs/error.log
    LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```

I am following instructions from book actually ,also changed `/etc/hosts` file , I added 192.168.36.1 magento.localhost.com. at the end , but when I try to open the site, it says :

> This webpage is not available

I enabled apache rewrite, give permission to all this folders ,basically did everything as instructions, but still not working. My os is `Ubuntu 14.04`, any tips ?

Comment: What version of Apache

Comment: You should include your file also in sites-enabled directory

Comment: Version is Apache2 ,site is included also using sudo a2ensite magento.localhost.com

Comment: First step is copy your Magento index.php somewhere else and create a new index.php just for testing. In that file, just put `<?php echo "hello world"; ?>`. Once that works, then try putting back the original Magento index.php.

Comment: Config looks fine to me. You've restarted apache after creating this file right?

Comment: I don't see how putting simple echo wolrd file will help,the problem is something in the configuration in Apache server and the virtual host.It will still say The webpage is not available

Comment: What is the OS that you use to connect magento.localhost.com? Are you using Windows or sth?

Comment: Os is Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Ok. I tought that you may be using Windows to connect your Ubuntu server. In that case you would need to modify Windows's hosts file too..

Comment: Change `Order allow,deny
        allow from all` to `Require all granted` That is correct Apache 2.4 syntax.

Comment: @dobrganch simple echo means less moving parts. In fact you should also rename htaccess file as well. Once you get hello world to work, then you can put back the htaccess. And then if that works, put back the Magento index.php

Comment: Also @RiggsFolly is right about Apache 2.4

Answer (score 0):

Follow recommendations in comments for `a2ensite` and for testing with a simple index.php file.

Also make sure to restart Apache.

When that works, then try with the Magento index.php file.

What you do next depends on if this is a brand new copy of Magento or a copy of a previously installed one. If it's new, you should see the setup page. Follow the instructions. If it's a copy, you will need to change the database `core_config_data` values relating to your website urls.

Edit:
You say

> changed /etc/hosts file ,I added 192.168.36.1

On what machine did you change this? Also is your Magento running in a virtual machine on your Windows machine? And the VM machine has that IP?

Edit 2:

Also change your web server name to "Magento.mysite.com" or something like that. `localhost` has a special meaning! And it doesn't make sense if you are accessing a remote we server!

Check web server ip with `ipconfig` or `ifconfig` on the command prompt. Put that ip in the hosts file of the **web browser machine**.

Comment: ok ,when I restart the Apache server ,it says : Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1.Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to supress this message.

Comment: @dobrganch That is irrelevant

Comment: Yeah ,I know ,it is still restarting ,I don't know where is the problem :)

Comment: @dobrganch yes that is a common message from Apache but you can ignore it forever. It doesn't matter, as Muhammedv said.

Comment: @ButtleButkus is on the right way, I also think that is a dns resolving problem too. I just realized that the error "This webpage is not available" is not an Apache error, it is a browser error message.

Comment: No its not virtual machine ,it is normal Ubuntu machine ,should I put different Ip adress there ?

Comment: When you visit http://192.168.36.1/ do you get a default apache page that says "It works!" ?

Comment: Put the IP address where? So you have two physical machines at your location. One has the web server. The other has your web browser. Did you edit the hosts file on the computer with the web browser? Because you probably have to.

Comment: Notice I edited my answer with that question for you. To access your web server machine by using that url, your web browser machine needs to know how to find it. You do that by editing the hosts file on the browsing machine, not on the web server machine.

Comment: No ,I didn't edit any host file ,can you tell me what I have to do edit ,so I can run Magento locally without using virtual machine ?

Comment: @dobrganch edit hosts file on your browsing machine to match up the domain name of your Magento site to the IP address of your Magento machine.

Comment: @ButtleButkus I think dobrganch using Ubuntu both as a desktop and a local server.

Comment: @muhammedv it seems so, but it's hard to get a clear answer from him. Either way, he needs to know the web server ip address and edit the web browser machine's host file. AND he should change that domain name. "Localhost" doesn't make sense if he is trying to access a web server on a *different machines*!